# How to fix fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib' on windows 11 in rust

Tags: windows, rust, gtk, gstreamer, rust-cargo

I am currently working on a project that uses the vid2img package, from what I know this package is using GStreamer and so I've followed on the steps on the installation guide and ran all the pacman installations with a msys2 terminal.

On my computer there are no problems with the below script but when using it on my laptop it really does not like it and constantly spits out an error saying fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gobject-2.0.lib'. I've tried reinstallting, rebooting, and changing environmental variables but nothing so far as worked and I'm incredibly lost. Are there any steps I can take to try solve this?

RUST CODE:

```rust
use std::path::Path;
use vid2img::FileSource;
use rusty_ytdl::{Video, VideoOptions, VideoQuality, VideoSearchOptions};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";
    download_video(url).await;
    create_frames().await;
}

async fn download_video(url: &str) {
    ...
    // this func works fine independently of project so removed to cut down on file (this just downloads the video and saves it as output.mp4
}

async fn create_frames() {
    let file_path = Path::new("output.mp4");

    let mut frame_id = 0;
    let frame_source = FileSource::new(file_path, (192, 182)).unwrap();
    for frame in frame_source.into_iter() {
        if let Ok(Some(_)) = frame {
            println!("Found frame! {}", frame_id);
            frame_id += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

CARGO.TOML:

```
[package]
name = "video_downloader"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["Julian"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gtk4 = "0.7.3"
rusty_ytdl = "0.6.3"
tokio = { version = "1.33.0", features = ["full"] }
vid2img = "0.1.1"
```

FULL ERROR LOG:
https://pastebin.com/X7JJ9j8P (used pastebin because it is very large)

Comment: Please make sure your question can be understood without requiring external resources such as pastebin, make it self contained!

Comment: @cafce25 this is why I put it in an external link:
I literally can't paste without running of of characters

Answer (score 1):

The exact same error occured for me. It seems that some linker options(`/LIBPATH`) are missing. However, I could not find a way to add it. One approach worked for me, though not clean one.

### Solution

1. We must have the lib in one of the `/LIBPATH` directories. You can find a `/LIBPATH` in the linker options: "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\user\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib". Let's call this directory A.
2. Search the lib(gobject-2.0.lib), and you should find one under 'release/lib'. Many libs are there. Copy all of them('.lib') to A.
3. `cargo build` again.

### Note

In my case, `cargo run` failed saying 'Entrypoint inflateReset2 missing in libpng16-16.dll'. That could be solved by copying zlib1.dll in gtk4 to the exe's directory.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but that seems to have worked!